# Spring boot don't upload data to database untill image loaded to server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am creating an admin panel for a website using spring boot and thymeleaf. An admin can add new product from the panel and also add the product's images. But usually uploading several images from client takes sometime. So when admin clicks upload button, i want first images fully uploaded to server and then all the data is added to database and admin redirected to main page. Is there anyway of doing that? Waiting for images to be completely uploaded to the server and then shown in the main page or else the data shows up without an image

```
var images = new ArrayList<Image>();
for (var image : model.getImages()) {
    Path path = Path.of("/img/" + image.getOriginalFilename());
images.add(new Image("img/" + image.getOriginalFilename(), shoe));
    try {
            Files.copy(
            image.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    imageService.saveAll(images);
}
```

Comment: You can disable the final add to the database button until all the images gets uploaded to the server and then when it is all complete you can enable the button.

Comment: @Ahmet Thanks for your response. I would like to know how can i implement that functionality? I edited my question and added the code I am using. Seems like File.copy is working in another thread and works async, so it is not waiting before adding images to database.